# koa js backend is showing error - DB not connected -how to fix this issue

Tags: koa, koa-router

I am also trying different network connections it returns the same error. Please help I am stuck last 15 days in this error. Oh! last one thing my laptop IP is dynamically changing so what can I do know.

this is my mongoose connecter

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const connection = () =>{
    const str = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/524'
    

    mongoose.connect(str , () =>{
        console.log("Connection is successfull")
    } )
}

module.exports = {connection }
```

this is server js

```
    const koa = require('koa')
const cors = require('koa-cors')
const bodyParser = require('koa-parser')
const json = require('koa-json')
const {connection} = require('./dal')


const userRouter = require('./Router/userRouter')


const app = new koa()

const PORT = 8000

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(json())

app.use(userRouter.routes()).use(userRouter.allowedMethods())

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
    connection();

})
```

this is modle class

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema ({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true

    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    role:{
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
},{
    timestamps:true
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = User
```

this is login route

> ```
>  const KoaRouter = require('koa-router')
>     const { register, login ,getAll } = require('../API/userAPI')
>     
>     const userRouter = new KoaRouter({prefix: '/user'})
>     
>     userRouter.post('/register', register)
>     userRouter.post('/login', login)
>     userRouter.get ('/get' , getAll)
>     
>     
>     module.exports = userRouter;
>
> this is my contraller  
>
>        const UserModel = require('../models/user.model')
>         const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
>         
>
>     
>     
>     const register = async (ctx) => {
>         try{
>             const user = ctx.request.body
>             const {name, email, password, role} = user
>     
>             if (!name || !email || !password){
>                 return (ctx.body = { message: "fill" });
>             }
>             else{
>                 const exist = await UserModel.findOne({email})
>                 if(exist){
>                     return (ctx.body = { message: "User already exists" });
>                 }else{
>     
>                     const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
>                     const hashpassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
>     
>                     const newUser = new UserModel({
>                         name,
>                         email,
>                         password : hashpassword,
>                         role
>                     })
>                     await newUser.save()
>                     return (ctx.body = { message: "User Registered" });
>                 }
>             }
>         }catch(err){
>             console.log(err.message)
>             return (ctx.body = { message: err.message });
>         }
>         
>     
>     }
>     
>     const login = async (ctx) => {
>         try{
>             const {email, password} = ctx.request.body
>             const user = await UserModel.findOne({email})
>     
>             if (!user){
>                 return ( ctx.body = {message:"User does not exist"})
>             }
>             else {
>                 const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
>                 if (!isMatch) {
>                    return (ctx.body = { message:"Wrong Password"})
>                 }else{
>                     return (ctx.body = { user})
>                 }
>             }
>     
>     
>         }catch(err){
>             return (ctx.body= {err})
>     
>         }
>     }
>     
>     const getAll = async (ctx) => {
>             try{
>                 const users = await UserModel.find()
>                 return (ctx.body = users)
>     
>         }catch(err){
>             return (ctx.body= {err})
>         }
>     
>     }
>     
>     
>     
>     
>     module.exports = {register, login ,getAll}
> ```

.

**how to fix this.any ideas.Can any body guide me with this scenario.**